# Sideloading images to imgur without API key

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, image-uploading, imgur

I've been trying to use the feature of the imgur API that allows you to just send a GET request to `http://api.imgur.com/2/upload` with a URL in the form data, and have that image uploaded, but I can't get it to work, it just returns nothing.

```
$.get("http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.json", {
  url: 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3e/Phalaenopsis_JPEG.png'
}, function(data) {
  return console.log(data);
});
```

Are there any alternatives? Or does anyone know how I can get the above code to work?

[*imgur API documentation here*](http://api.imgur.com/resources_anon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, it was in fact working!

The location of the uploaded image was being returned as `Location` in the response headers.

**Edit:**

I found that I wasn't able to access the headers so I had to come up with something else. Here's a snippet to upload using YQL:

```
urlToImgur = (url, callback) ->
  upload_url = "http://api.imgur.com/2/upload?url=#{url}"
  $.ajax
    url: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql'
    dataType: 'jsonp'
    data:
      q: "select none from html where url='#{upload_url}'"
      diagnostics: true
    success: (data) ->
      redirects = data.query.diagnostics.redirect
      image_url = redirects[redirects.length-1].content
      callback image_url
```